# How to formulate what Lang is getting at with associativity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, associativity

Lang mentions in his graduate algebra textbook that commutativity can make sense in the context of a map involving $S$ and $T$:

$$S \times S \rightarrow T$$

in that $xy = yx$ can possibly hold true (I think I am understanding that right), *i.e.*, a situation more general than a monoid law of composition. He goes on to suggest that the reader should think about the most general combination of sets for which associativity can work.

I don't really understand what he's getting at here, and I was trying to formulate it. Given sets some sets $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, and $F$, there may be mappings $A\times B\xrightarrow{f} C$, $C\times D\xrightarrow{g} E$, $B\times D\xrightarrow{h} F$, and $A\times F\xrightarrow{i} E$, then the following compositions could make sense:

$$(xy)z = x(yz)$$

where $x\in A$, $y\in B$, and $z\in C$.

I don't know if I am getting what the author is saying.

Reference: [Google books highlight](https://books.google.com/books?id=eOUlBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=lang%20%22formulate%20the%20most%20general%20combination%20of%20sets%20under%20which%20it%20will%20work%22&source=bl&ots=6wV7HffLQr&sig=XvpLXD_v6zMPKDtiSe5mAnI_H3g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlvNiKzJ7fAhWoGTQIHZ5lAk0Q6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=lang%20%22formulate%20the%20most%20general%20combination%20of%20sets%20under%20which%20it%20will%20work%22&f=false)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that seems to be what Lang is saying. Given sets* $A,B,C,D,E,F$ and functions*
\begin{align*}
f : A\times B&\to D,\\
g : B\times C&\to E,\\
h : D\times C&\to F,\\
i : A\times E&\to F,
\end{align*}
then we might say a *generalized associativity* for the above data holds if for any $a\in A,$ $b\in B,$ $c\in C,$ $$h(f(a,b),c) = i(a,g(b,c)).$$

More succinctly, we can summarize by saying that the following diagram of sets commutes:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A\times B\times C @>{f\times \textrm{id}_C}>> D\times C;\\
@VV{\textrm{id}_A\times g}V @VV{h}V \\
A\times E @>{i}>> F.
\end{CD}
$$

You could also formulate similar "higher associativity" statements for "products" of four or more elements, although the diagrams you need to commute become increasingly more cumbersome...

*Feel free to replace "sets" by "objects in some category" and "functions" by "morphisms" everywhere. Of course, if you do, you can't use the element-wise description of this generalized associativity.